# Using Mongodb aggregate to get the total ordered qty of a product across all orders

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm pretty new to javascript. I'm working on a dashboard, and I want to be able to see the total quantity of each product ordered. I have a variable qty for the quantity of an individual product, but I'm struggling with how to get the total quantity of an individual product from all of my orders. Below, I've included what I have and any documents that I felt might be useful. I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to do this.

part from orderRouter.js

```
  const qty = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$name',
          count: { $sum:'$qty'},
        },
      },
    ]);
```

orderRouter.js

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import Order from '../models/orderModel.js';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';
import Product from '../models/productModel.js';
import {isAdmin, isAuth, isSellerOrAdmin} from '../utils.js';

const orderRouter = express.Router();
orderRouter.get(
  '/',
  isAuth,
  isSellerOrAdmin,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const seller = req.query.seller || '';
    const sellerFilter = seller ? { seller } : {};
    const orders = await Order.find({ ...sellerFilter }).populate(
      'user',
      'name',
    );
    res.send(orders);
  })
);



orderRouter.get(
  '/summary',
  isAuth,
  isAdmin,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const orders = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$name',
          count: { $sum:'$qty'},
        },
      },
    ]);
    res.send({ qty  });
  })
);

orderRouter.get(
  '/mine',
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const orders = await Order.find({ user: req.user._id });
    res.send(orders);
  })
);
orderRouter.post(
  '/',
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.orderItems.length === 0) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: 'Cart is empty' });
    } else {
      const order = new Order({
        seller: req.body.orderItems[0].seller,
        orderItems: req.body.orderItems,
        shippingAddress: req.body.shippingAddress,
        paymentMethod: req.body.paymentMethod,
        itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice,
        shippingPrice: req.body.shippingPrice,
        taxPrice: req.body.taxPrice,
        totalPrice: req.body.totalPrice,
        user: req.user._id,
      });
      const createdOrder = await order.save();
      res
        .status(201)
        .send({ message: 'New Order Created', order: createdOrder });
    }
  })
);
orderRouter.get(
  '/:id',
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id);
    if (order) {
      res.send(order);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Order Not Found' });
    }
  })
);

export default orderRouter;
```

orderModel.js

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Product',
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
);
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
export default Order;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you may need the following

```
collections = [
  {
    orderedItems: [
      {
        name: "product 1",
        qty: 20,
        image: "image1",
        price: 200,
        product: {
          type: "2222",
          ref: "Product",
          
        },
        
      },
      {
        name: "product 1",
        qty: 40,
        image: "image2",
        price: 300,
        product: {
          type: "333",
          ref: "Product",
          
        },
        
      },
      
    ]
  }
]
```

Use `$unwind` to separate the array of items

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$orderedItems"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$orderedItems.name",
      count: {
        $sum: "$orderedItems.qty"
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

Output would be

```
[
  {
    "_id": "product 1",
    "count": 60
  }
]
```

Check the [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lLGOyUMmvvr)